# Eclipse replace Assertions with StricAssertions when organizing imports

Tags: java, eclipse, import, assertions

We have an import problem with Eclipse :

the test class uses Assertions.assertThat

When hitting Ctrl + Shift + O to organize the imports, Eclipse replace Assertions.assertThat with StrictAssertions.assertThat

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TheTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() {
        assertThat(2).isEqualTo(2);
    }
}
```

is replaced with :

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.StrictAssertions.assertThat;  // change here !

import org.junit.Test;

public class TheTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() {
        assertThat(2).isEqualTo(2);
    }
}
```

And when we have some specific asserts that are only in Assertions (for lists), Eclipse add StrictAssertions to the imports.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TheTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() {
        assertThat(2).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(new ArrayList<>()).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

is changed to :

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.StrictAssertions.assertThat;  // this import was added 

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TheTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() {
        assertThat(2).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(new ArrayList<>()).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

It seems that Assertions extends StrictAssertions, so their is no problem using StrictAssertions, but why is Eclipse not using the extended class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, because `assertThat(int actual)` is defined in `StrictAssertions` and not hidden by `Assertions`, Eclipse decides to import from `StrictAssertions`.

Also, for organizing imports Eclipse seems to ignore *Type Filters* - so even that won't help.

> It seems that Assertions extends StrictAssertions, so their is no problem using StrictAssertions

Not for your current setup, but `StrictAssertions` has been removed with [AssertJ 3.2.0](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.2.0). So when upgrading to a newer version of `AssertJ` `StrictAssertions` will get in your way.

I'd suggest you upgrade to *3.2.0 or later*, if it is possible with your project.

Comment: Well, it seems that Tests using 
                assertThat(file).hasSameContentAs(refFile);

are not passing any more...
but when trying to check 2 dummy files, it is working...

Comment: @GaspardP hmm, works in my tests. did you set/check the file encoding?

Comment: Well, we found a way : 
hasSameContent compare 2 strings in V3.2.0 and was comparing to Binary file in V3.1.0.
and in our test we needed to compare binary files.

Comment: So we are using a little hack : 
                byte[] expectedContent = Files.readAllBytes(refFile.toPath());
                assertThat(file).hasBinaryContent(expectedContent);

and it's know working.